# what is cats / fs2 equivalent of ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect

I found [fs2-cron](https://github.com/fthomas/fs2-cron) but its not same as invoking task with fixed delay interval.  If this feature is available in cats/fs2 could you please provide code example.  I did look at cats Timer but could not figure out how to repeat the task with interval.

One way to do it would be as below, but I assume adding a Thread.sleep is not the right way to do it.

```
Stream.eval(IO {
  println("BEING RUN!!");
  Thread.sleep(5000)
})
  .repeat
  .compile
  .drain
  .as(ExitCode.Success)
```

Thanks
Saad.

Comment: Can't you just create a `Pipe` that given a `Stream`, delays it's execution? You can just then run the Stream through the pipe before doing anything else

Answer (score 3):

Using `Thread.sleep` is not the best way for introducing delay, since it will block the thread for 5 seconds.

Usually, a better alternative is using `IO.sleep`, which will not block the thread, just "hang" task for a given time-period and then reschedule it again.

```
Stream.eval(
  for {
    _ <- IO(println("BEING RUN!!"))
    _ <- IO.sleep(5.seconds)
  } yield ()
).repeat
  .compile
  .drain
  .as(ExitCode.Success)
```

Even better you could use `fs2` built-in function `awakeEvery` to emit a single element from a stream in a fixed interval and then execute effect on every element of the stream.

```
Stream.awakeEvery[IO](5.seconds)
    .evalMap(_ => IO(println("BEING RUN!!")))
    .compile
    .drain
    .as(ExitCode.Success)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example it helped find what I need, which is awakeDelay, which seems equivalent to scheduleWithFixedDelay

Comment: You can upvote/accept if you found it helpful.